# Extend Playframework 2.0 build system to compress (gzip) assets

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

From what I understand from ["Playframework's working with public assets"](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Assets), it will serve the asset by serving a compressed version (with suffix .gz) if it exists.

Now I want to know whether there is way to automatically compress the public assets as part of the build process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this topic: [Gzipping assets](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/dSJEKhYiMDE/u-N50plw6hwJ), it's exactly what you're looking for.

It will add a new sbt task which gzip all assets, and automatic launch this command when `dist`/`start`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it work for `play start`, as far as I could test, it doesn't package the gzipped files when you run `play dist` or `play stage`.

If you need to create a binary package for deploying in production, see my answer at [Play Framework 2.0.4 GZip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960943/play-framework-2-0-4-gzip/18130518#18130518), it solved my problem.