# Play Framework 2.0.4 GZip

Tags: playframework-2.0, gzip

I want Play to send GZipped JS and CSS to the browser.
In the Build.scala, I added

```
 val gzipAssets = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gzip-assets", "GZIP all assets")
 lazy val gzipAssetsSetting = gzipAssets <<= gzipAssetsTask
 lazy val gzipAssetsTask = (gzippableAssets, streams) map {
  case (finder: PathFinder, s: TaskStreams) => {
    finder.get.map { file =>
      val gzTarget = new File(file.getAbsolutePath + ".gz")
      IO.gzip(file, gzTarget)
      s.log.info("Compressed " + file.getAbsolutePath + " " + file.length / 1000 + " k     => " + gzTarget.getName + " " + gzTarget.length / 1000 + " k")
      gzTarget
    }
  }
}

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
    // Twitter Bootstrap v2.0.1 compilation (https://plus.google.com/u/0/108788785914419775677/posts/QgyUF9cXPkv)
    lessEntryPoints <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(base => ((base / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "twitterbootstrap" / "styles.less"))),

    // set up gzip of assets
    gzippableAssets <<= (resourceManaged in (ThisProject))(dir => ((dir ** "*.js") +++ (dir ** "*.css"))),
    gzipAssetsSetting,
    playPackageEverything <<= playPackageEverything dependsOn gzipAssets


).settings( ...
```

which generates me files in the target when I dist :

[info] Compressed /Users/wimha/Documents/**/target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/stylesheets/twitterbootstrap/styles.min.css 183 k => styles.min.css.gz 27 k

but then, in prod, the file is not available :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://ec2-54-228-70-193.eu-west- 1.compute.amazonaws.com/assets/stylesheets/twitterbootstrap/styles.min.css.gz

I have 2 questions :

- Why isn't the file available ?
- Do you have a better solution ? Maybe with a module ? I didn't find something interesting excepted GreenScript but it's only for Play 1.x
  I'd like to have my assets also merged in one file.

Thanks
Julien

Answer (score 1):

I lost hours looking for a solution for the same problem.

Try this: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/841-gzip-assets. It will package the `.gz` files whether you run `play dist` or `play stage`.

> Given that Play is already smart enough to serve assets gzipped when a
>   corresponding .gz file exists, it would make sense to gzip assets when
>   doing 'stage' or 'dist'. Some reverse proxies can gzip resources, but
>   this is either less efficient (if done for each request) or more
>   complicated (if resources are cached, and can end up being stale).
>
> Here's a half-baked solution using the Build.scala:
>
> ```
> val gzippableAssets = SettingKey[PathFinder]("gzippable-assets", "Defines the files to gzip")
> val gzipAssets = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gzip-assets", "gzip all assets")
> lazy val gzipAssetsSetting = gzipAssets <<= gzipAssetsTask dependsOn (copyResources in Compile)
> lazy val gzipAssetsTask = (gzippableAssets, streams) map {
>   case (finder: PathFinder, s: TaskStreams) => {
>     var count = 0
>     var files = finder.get.map { file =>
>       val gzTarget = new File(file.getAbsolutePath + ".gz")
>       IO.gzip(file, gzTarget)
>       count += 1;
>       gzTarget
>     }
>     s.log.info("Compressed " + count + " asset(s)")
>     files
>   }
> }
>
> val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
>     ...
>     gzippableAssets <<= (classDirectory in Compile)(dir => (dir ** ("*.js" || "*.css" || "*.html"))),
>     gzipAssetsSetting,
>     playPackageEverything <<= playPackageEverything dependsOn gzipAssets
> )
> ```